# Close to move to sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion

I see a number of SharePoint question on StackOverflow. Having worked for a year or so with SharePoint I always asked my questions on the sharepoint.stackexchange.com site as I decided that they would have the best expert knowledge and it seemed the right place to ask those questions.

Many people don't do this however, I've seen 2 questions in the last half hour about SharePoint. I'm wondering - should I be voting to close/migrate these to sharepoint.stackexchange.com? I feel like it detracts from the alternative site if they're posted here, but on the other hand, most are not strictly off topic if programming related.

Comment: You could suggest that the user asks the question there instead since it is dedicated to sharepoint. Most people want an answer now, so they should want to move to a specialized sub. Forcing people into things (and a lot of computer guys are autistic) will only make them leave.

Comment: In the past 90 days, only 12 posts were migrated to Sharepoint. You can always leave a comment informing the OP about the existence of Sharepoint SE, and / or use a moderator flag requesting migration of *quality* questions. The latter should only be used for questions that are *off topic* for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It's already there as a close vote migration option - I'm just wondering if I should really be selecting it or if really I should choose to leave those questions on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Ian: oops, so it is! :-)

Comment: @Ian: interesting, as it is currently 10th in the stats, albeit with 0 rejections in the past 3 months.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a programming question that happens to involve programming in a SharePoint environment then the question is on topic on SO.  If the question is about SharePoint (as an environment) then the question belongs on SharePoint.SE.

It's not terribly different from any other application that sits on a platform, say a PHP application sitting on a web server.  If the question is a programming question then it goes on SO.  If it's a question about the platform rather than about the code that sits on it, then it's likely that the question would belong on Server Fault or Super User.  In this case, SP simply has it's own special site for questions about the platform.

Comment: While I agree in general - SharePoint.SE is also for SharePoint programming questions and is a less active community so may benefit from these specific questions. So really questions sit well on both.

Comment: @Ian If it's a programming question then it's on topic on SO and shouldn't be migrated.  If it's also on topic on SP.SE, then likewise if the question is asked there it shouldn't be migrated to SO either.  Sites are allowed to have an overlap.  That said, the primary purpose of SP.SE is to have a place for all of the non-programming related SP questions (even if code is involved in the question somehow).