# Allow per-tag migration reasons

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, migration

As far as I know, the sites shown in the Close→Off-topic→Migration dialog are selected based on SO-wide migration statistics. There has been discussions in the past whether to keep or remove a particular site from this list (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263027/245183), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261072/245183), and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250056/245183)).

From a global, SO-wide perspective I am sure the statistics play nicely. However, from the perspective of a tag such as [sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint), a close reason allowing the migration to the [SharePoint SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) site is obviously missing and makes the life of those casting the close votes as well as moderators a bit more difficult.

Specifically, in the SharePoint community, there are dozens of programming questions which are on-topic on SO and dozens of non-programming questions are off-topic on SO, and both types are being asked on SO. It is clear that the second type needs to be migrated. In this particular case, a proper migration target would be very helpful. However, *this shall be understood as a single example only*.

I suggest that it should be possible to specify a custom migration target on a per-tag basis. This solution would preserve the statistics-based common migration targets and satisfy the needs of sub-communities such as SharePoint and others mentioned in the questions I've linked above.

---

*Because of past heated discussions regarding this matter, let me for the sake of clarity emphasize that I am **not** proposing to include SharePoint SE as a migration target on the whole SO.*

Comment: I'm more curious as to why we're not allowed to choose from a list of all Stack Exchange sites when closing for migration...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Because it leads to lots of invalid (erroneous) migrations that annoy those other sites. If you're not extremely familiar with the migration destination and it's guidelines, you should not be suggesting migration there. Having a list encourages those poorly selected or informed migrations. (This has been discussed at length in prior questions here. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251652/62576 for one, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253869/62576 for another.)

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, I figured there was a discussion about this somewhere but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @DanielA.White Great! Exactly what I am suggesting. However, I didn't find this question before. Good to knoe this has been an issue for some while.